# How to preg_replace with incremental counted numbers using php?

Tags: php, regex, php-5.3

I need to replace a certain pattern with incremental counted numbers.
My code:

```
$text = "Hello (apple) hello (banana) hello (cucumber)";
$pattern = '/\(([^\)]*)\)/s';

$i = 0;
$returnText = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use ($i) {
    return '<sup>['.$i++.']</sup>';
}, $text);

echo $returnText;
```

The result:

```
Hello [0] hello [0] hello [0]
```

What i need:

```
Hello [0] hello [1] hello [2]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to pass $i by reference. Just add the **&** before **$i**:

```
$returnText = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use (&$i)
```